# Android studio devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, adb

Once or twice a day Android Studio doesn't recognize any devices attached to my computer. Even

```
adb devices
```

doesn't show anything. The only thing that makes my devices reappear is restarting my computer. Even

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

doesn't show any devices. Does anybody know why and how I can make adb recognise my devices without restarting my computer?

Comment: Do you have the correct USB drivers for your Android device?

Comment: I suppose I have since it works fine most of the time

Comment: Is your cable broken?

Comment: Do you happen to be using a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something strange with my USB port I reckon. Reinserting the cable mostly fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check lsusb , if your cable or usb port have problem your device does not appear
otherwise if you see your device in list and your adb devices is empty, maybe the problem is adb files config, check your VENDOR ID in adb_usb.ini , the VENDOR ID must be same as lsusb id

Comment: Will do when I'm home.